# Can you submit an app via the free VM's from Microsoft?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-8.1-universal

This is not a programming question, but the kind of people who will know the answer to this are programmers on this site (which is why this is a better place to post, rather than superuser).

You can download free  Windows 8.1 Vm from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

And free windows 10 Vm from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

I'm developing a cross platform app (iOS, Android, Windows 8), so all my development is done on a Mac, and I need a Windows Vm just to compile and submit. Does anyone know whether there are any restrictions on using the free VM (without license key), to submit an app to the windows store ?

Comment: Nothing technical, surely. There may be a licensing issue, but that's kinda off topic here and I'm not a lawyer. Most likely wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - The last time I submitted an app via my licensed copy of Windows 8, I had to "activate" visual studio with some kind of account to allow me to test on a device, and to submit.